# Can K-means put most of the noise in the same cluster?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, natural-language, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am working on clustering text data (very short sentences) vectorized with tf-idf. The data are characterized by high sparseness and the presence of abundant noise (considered here as documents that I don't expect to belong to any cluster). I managed to make DBSCAN work relatively well on the data as I know that, given their characteristic. it was a better option than K-means. I had still tried to use K-means just to see what happens and, curiosly, it seems that K-means, even if its performance are pretty poor, manages to collect most of the noise documents in the same cluster (which is also the biggest as expected).
Plotting the shilouette score for the points in each cluster we can see this:
[image: Shilouette score for each cluster]

All cluster except cluster zero have mostly (low) positive shilouette values and, actually, if i check what's inside cluster 0 I find (mostly) documents that I expected to belong to noise.

Do you think this is possible and it is something that can be expected to happens with K-means? I can imagine that this depends on the distribution of the data but, as I am still novice, I'd like to have more hints on what's happening.

My first question here so I hope it's legit.
Many thanks

Comment: Was cluster 0 indeed formed by k-means clustering procedure? It would be interesting to look on data  pictures like scatterplots how that cluster really looks like.

Comment: Yes in the post I am referring to the results obtained with k-means. Regarding the scatterplot we are talking about textual data so with very high dimensionality, thus plotting is not necessarily helpful as a big dimensionality reduction is required and it cannot be guaranteed that structure is preserved (indeed, in the case of my data, plotting wasn't helpful)